# how to make bootstrap media heading a hyperlink ?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to add a link to the media heading  i tried the code bellow but the output is simple media text no hyperlink :

```
 <h4 class = "media-heading" <a href="<?php echo $tablelink2[$i]; ?>" title="<?php echo $tabletitle2[$i]; ?> " ><?php echo $tabletitle2[$i]; ?></a></h4>
```

any help please ?

addition : please if you know any tutorial or library usefull for adding responsive media objects ( img + hyperlink) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you're missing one of the closing brackets on the opening h4 tag in your example. Try this:

```
<h4 class = "media-heading"> <a href="<?php echo $tablelink2[$i]; ?>" title="<?php echo $tabletitle2[$i]; ?> " ><?php echo $tabletitle2[$i]; ?></a></h4>
```

Comment: Well, we all do mistakes, but try to double check next time before posting the question.